# Ruby on rails: Extracting multidimensional array from JSON to a corresponding model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, json

I am handling JSON which has a structure like this:

```
 "meals" {"en": [
    ["Monday chicken sticks","Monday mozzarella salad"],
    [  "Tuesday schnitzel", "Tuesday soup"],
    [ "Spaghetti à la Wednesday"],
    ["Thursday salmon"],
    ["Curry of Friday"],
    ["Saturday sausages"]}
  ]
```

So the indices of "en" array correspond to days of a week and inner arrays to menus for that day.

Now my problem is that I'm trying to save the data to database as serialized array. I can do this manually, but not when parsing JSON. My code looks something like this:

```
@meal = Meal.new #Meal is a model that contains the array
  #item is HTTParty response object
  @meal.en = item["meals"]["en"] #this is where program crashes: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
  @meal.save
```

I guess I'm approaching the assignment wrong or it cannot be done in the first place. Is there a way around this or should I make a model for days with a single dimension array containing the menu for that day?

Comment: Looks like either meals or en doesn't exist in one of the items

Comment: I had a hunch that this was about some minor oversight and embarrassingly I had assumed that JSON always included 'en' array even if it was empty. Now with

     @meal.en = item["meals"]["en"] unless item["meals"]["en"].nil?

it works just fine. Thank you Baloo for guiding the blind.

Comment: A little addition: The syntax was also wrong. It should have been @meal.en = item["meals"["en"]]

Answer (score 1):

So you want to save arrays in your db?

If you perform `item["meals"]["en"]`, you're going to have Monday with two entries - how does that work? You need to be able to give each attribute of your model a single entry, like this:

```
 "meals":
  {"en": 
    {
      "Monday":    ["chicken sticks", "mozzarella salad"],
      "Tuesday":   ["schnitzel", "soup"],
      "Wednesday": ["spaghetti"],
      "Thursday":  ["salmon"],
      "Friday":    ["curry"],
      "Saturday":  ["sausages"]
    }
  }
```

If you construct your JSON like this, it will allow you to save into the different attributes of your db. I'd then set up my tables like this:

```
meals
   id 
   name

menu 
   id
   day

meals_menus
   meal_id
   menu_id
```

This will allow you to save a meal as `chicken sticks`, assigning it to `monday`. You'd set up your models like this:

```
#app/models/meal.rb
Class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :menus
end

#app/models/menu.rb
Class Menu < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :meals
end
```